# reclassify fields in one column of a table depending on criteria

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following table:

```
person       drug
------       -----
1            Y
2            Y
2            other
3            X
4            X
5            X
5            other
6            other
7            Z
```

However, if there is a person where they have a drug `x,y,z` (it will only be one distinct choice) plus 'other' - then I want to **remove the row that contains other**

This would mean that someone with an 'X' and 'other' would remove the row conatining 'other', but anyone with only 'other' will stay as 'other'. i.e.

```
person       drug
------       -----
1            Y
2            Y
3            X
4            X
5            X
6            other
7            Z
```

where person 6 only has other, so stays that way, but persons 2 and 5 have the 'other' rows removed because they have other drug choices (x,y or z).

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: . . Why is this tagged for both MySQL and DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear whether you want this removed in the results of a query or in the data itself.  To return results without this row from a query, which can be written like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where not (t.drug = 'other' and
           exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.person = t.person and t2.drug = 'x')
          )
```

To handle any of 'x', 'y', or 'z', change the last statement to `t2.drug in ('x', 'y', 'z')`.

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. it returns the same table. maybe I have overlooked something in your code so I'll keep trying.

Comment: @brucezepplin . . . My fault.  The subquery had the wrong alias on `drug`.  Fixed.

Comment: no problem at all. I should have spotted this myself. all works now. Thanks for your help.